# Which build constraint clauses to use to distiguish 32-bit from 64-bit integers?

Tags: go, build, int

I want to define a constant whose numeric value depends on whether `int` is a 32-bit or a 64-bit type on a particular target architecture. It's possible to compile go source files conditionally using [Build constraints](https://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints).

Are there simple build constraint clauses with predefined tags which select for one or the other? Ideally, something like:

```
//+build 32bit
```

Otherwise, I'd either have to somehow detect the size externally and use custom build tags, or maintain a large list of predefined target tags which may change with each go release. Is there a simpler way?

Comment: There is no built-in build constraint specifically on the size of `int`. You could try to target this based on `GOARCH` (e.g. `386` vs `amd64`, `arm` vs `arm64`, etc.). This seems like a very likely XY problem though - *why* are you trying to do this?